# Opencart v.1.5.3.1 - empty div banner

Tags: opencart, banner

I am using **Opencart v.1.5.3.1**.
I am experiencing a problem with displaying banners.
What I get is an empty div like this...

```
<div id="banner1" class="banner"> </div>
```

I have double checked that I have setup banners correctly in...

**System->Design->Banners**

and

**Modules->Banners**

I can't understand where the error is in...

```
catalog/view/theme/myTheme/template/module/banner.tpl
```

I believe the problem is in here...

```
<?php foreach ($banners as $banner) { ?>
...
<?php } ?>
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: can you var_dump($banners) and paste the result here?

Comment: And what the size for banners have you set??

Comment: The result from var_dump($banners) is...  array(0) {}

Comment: That is seemed that you does not set the banner correctly

Comment: If you have such result  array(0) {} -t means than there is no banner was selected from your DB - and that's mean that you did not set up the banner correctly

Comment: If you solved your problem, please, write

Comment: The author of the theme says that is compatible only with Opencart v.1.5.4+. Is it possible that this might cause the problem?

Comment: Can you give the site url, I will see it on Back office or  give some pictures what are you set on to turned the banner

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41200/discussion-between-sergio-and-kanenas-net)

Comment: site: http://www.ztools.gr/index.php?route=product/category&path=116 img->http://www.ztools.gr/image/data/TLS_020313_1.jpg img->cache->http://www.ztools.gr/image/cache/data/TLS_020313_1-100x100.jpg 

Thank you for your interest!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that in your template file you have not a left_side bar that's why the banner can not visible on category page, hope it will help!